Spin squared in terms of density and double occupancy
I am having trouble reproducing Fradkin's Equation (2.23) in Field Theories of Condensed Matter.
$$
\sum_\vec{r} \left(\vec{S}(\vec{r})\right)^2 
= \sum_\vec{r} \left(\frac{3}{4} n (\vec{r}) - \frac{3}{2} n_\uparrow(\vec{r}) n_\downarrow(\vec{r}) \right)
$$
Where he invokes the completeness relation
$${\displaystyle {\vec {\sigma }}_{\alpha \beta }\cdot {\vec {\sigma }}_{\gamma \delta }\equiv \sum _{k=1}^{3}\sigma _{\alpha \beta }^{k}\,\sigma _{\gamma \delta }^{k}=2\,\delta _{\alpha \delta }\,\delta _{\beta \gamma }-\delta _{\alpha \beta }\,\delta _{\gamma \delta }.}$$
And from the Jordan map $\vec{S}(\vec{r}) = \frac{\hbar}{2} c^\dagger_\alpha(\vec{r}) \vec{\sigma}^{\alpha \beta} c_\beta(\vec{r})$ and  $n_\alpha^2 = n_\alpha = c^\dagger_\alpha c_\alpha$ for fermions with the normal anti-commutation relations.
I first tried it using Fradkin's method:
$$
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \left(\vec{S}(\vec{r})\right)^2
    &=  S^a(\vec{r}) S_a(\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \sum_a
    [c^\dagger_\alpha \sigma_a^{\alpha \beta} c_\beta
    c^\dagger_\gamma \sigma_a^{\gamma \delta} c_\delta] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
    (2 \delta^{\alpha \delta} \delta^{\beta \gamma} - \delta^{\alpha \beta} \delta^{\gamma \delta})
    [c^\dagger_\alpha c_\beta c^\dagger_\gamma c_\delta] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \sum_{\alpha, \beta}
    [2 c^\dagger_\alpha c_\beta c^\dagger_\beta c_\alpha - c^\dagger_\alpha c_\alpha c^\dagger_\beta c_\beta] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4} \sum_{\alpha, \beta}
    [-2 c^\dagger_\alpha c_\alpha c^\dagger_\beta c_\beta  + 4 c^\dagger_\alpha c_\alpha - c^\dagger_\alpha c_\alpha c^\dagger_\beta c_\beta] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= - \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
      [3 (n_\uparrow + n_\downarrow)^2 - 4 n] (\vec{r}) \\
    &=  -\frac{\hbar^2}{4}
      [6 n_\uparrow n_\downarrow + 3 (n_\uparrow^2 + n_\downarrow^2) - 4 (n_\uparrow + n_\downarrow)] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \hbar^2
      \left[\frac{n}{4} - \frac{3}{2} n_\uparrow n_\downarrow\right] (\vec{r})
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$
I at first thought this was a mistake in Fradkin where he accidentally used $\{c, c\}$ as $1$ instead of $0$ when doing the other two $\{c^\dagger, c\} = 1$,
but when I brute force it, it seems to work (I haven't checked this for errors):
$$
    \begin{aligned}
     \left(\vec{S}(\vec{r})\right)^2
    &=  S^a(\vec{r}) S_a(\vec{r}) \\     
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
      [(
      c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow + c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow,
      \mathrm{i} c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow - \mathrm{i} c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow,
      c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow - c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow
      )^2
      ] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
      \left[
      \begin{aligned}
      &\phantom{+}\,\, (c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow  c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow + c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow +
      c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow + c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow) \\
      &- (c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow  c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow -  c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow  c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow
      - c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow  c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow  +  c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow  c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow) \\
      &+ (c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow - c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow
      - c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow + c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow)
      \end{aligned}
      \right] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
      \left[ 2c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow + 2c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\uparrow
      + c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow - c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow - c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow + c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow
      \right] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
    \left[ -2c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow   + 2c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow
    - 2c_\uparrow^\dagger  c_\uparrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow + 2c_\uparrow^\dagger  c_\uparrow
      + c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow - c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow - c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\uparrow^\dagger c_\uparrow + c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow c_\downarrow^\dagger c_\downarrow
      \right] (\vec{r}) \\
    &= \frac{\hbar^2}{4}
    \left[ -2n_\downarrow n_\uparrow   + 2n_\downarrow
    - 2n_\uparrow n_\downarrow + 2n_\uparrow
      + n_\uparrow n_\uparrow - n_\uparrow n_\downarrow - n_\downarrow n_\uparrow + n_\downarrow n_\downarrow
      \right] (\vec{r}) \\
   &= \frac{3\hbar^2}{4}
    \left[n_\uparrow   + n_\downarrow - 2n_\downarrow n_\uparrow
      \right] (\vec{r}) \\
    \end{aligned}
$$
Not to mention, this latter attempt and Fradkin's version make more physical sense if one takes expectation values for some simple examples.
I either have a very silly mistake, or there is some property I am neglecting. Or am I doing something illegal with my contractions?

Okay, this is one of those silly index mistakes. One has to remember that $\sum_{\alpha, \beta} \delta^{\beta \beta} n_\alpha = 2 \sum_\alpha n_\alpha$ where $\alpha, \beta \in \{\uparrow,\downarrow\}$. Of course, the $2$ could be exchanged for whatever number of indices $\beta$ runs over.
Let me go through each anticommutation.
$$
2 c^\dagger_\alpha c^\beta c^\dagger_\beta c^\alpha
= -2c^\dagger_\alpha c^\dagger_\beta c^\beta   c^\alpha + 2\delta^{\beta}_{\beta} c^\dagger_\alpha c_\alpha
= -2c^\dagger_\alpha  c^\alpha c^\dagger_\beta c^\beta   + 2\delta^{\beta}_{\beta} c^\dagger_\alpha c^\alpha + 2{\delta}{^{\alpha}_{\phantom{\alpha}\beta}}c^\dagger_\alpha c^\beta  = -2 n^2 + 6n
$$
Propagating this change resolves the issue. Don't be sloppy, write out your Kronecker Deltas.
